# How can I start processing audio on Orange Pi zero {A board similar to Rpi}?

Tags: audio, wolfson-audio-card

Orange pi is similar board to the Rpi except some extra features such as built-in audio card. I am new to this board as well as Linux.
I have a [orange Pi zero](http://www.orangepi.org/orangepizero/) and I want to start with some simple task such as attaching a microphone and taking input from microphone and save as raw file. 
I would really appreciate if you can give me link or book where I can read about it thoroughly. It also would be great if you can give feedback based on your personal experience.
Following is the pinout of the board.[image: Pinlayout]
{Note: Before deleting my post please consider that Orange pi is very similar to Rpi so this is very relevant forum to discuss it. Thanks}

Comment: Non Raspberry Pi questions are explicitly off-topic per the site's FAQ.

Comment: Orange pi is very similar board. Please don't delete it as orange pi forums are very rare.

Comment: The fact that the Orange Pi forums/community is small in comparison to the Raspberry Pi community does not make your question on topic, and is something you should have considered before buying.

Comment: Can you suggest a forum where I can discuss processing of audio on a Linux based board.

Comment: Have you considered whatever support channel is offered by the manufacturer/seller of the board. As a self professed noob take this as a learning experience - community size and sales numbers trump price.

Comment: No helping. I think as we are working on Linux, it would be same no matter what board we are using. Your thoughts?

Comment: The "question" would have been closed, even if about Raspberry Pi because it is opinion based.

Comment: Why don't you buy raspberry pi zero then? I mean... if orange pi zero support is so bad, that you can't even find anything on how to use it, why did you buy it in the first place :)

Comment: What I need is begginer guide to get going for audio on linux with audio port.  Help would be greatly appreciated.